# Deleting an object in a function C++

Tags: c++

I have a simple question.

Consider the code below:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Node {
    int data;
    Node *left;
    Node *right;
    Node(int pData) : data(pData), left(nullptr), right(nullptr) {}
};

void delete_node(Node *node) {
    delete node;
    node = nullptr;
}

int main() {
    Node *node1 = new Node(1);
    Node *node2 = new Node(2);
    delete_node(node1);
    delete node2;
    node2 = nullptr;
    if (node1) std::cout << "node1: " << node1->data << std::endl;
    if (node2) std::cout << "node2: " << node2->data << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Which produces the output:

```
node1: -572662307
```

Which I find odd since I set `node1 = nullptr` in function `delete_node`. Can someone please explain?

Comment: Change the function signature to `void delete_node(Node *&node)`

Comment: One thing I'd like to add (the duplicate doesn't address): You won't get into the same trouble with `std::unique_ptr`: `void destroy(std::unique_ptr<whatEver> object)`. Unique pointers cannot be copied, so you are forced to move them: `std::unique_ptr<...> p; destroy(std::move(p));` leaving the outer pointer at empty state (even before the function call). Additional advantage: Self-documenting code. Already the function signature shows that the function will take ownership of the object.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The line

```
node = nullptr;
```

changes the value of the function local variable. It does not change the value of `node1` in the calling function.

Change the function to accept its argument by reference.

```
// node is a reference to the pointer
void delete_node(Node*& node) {
    delete node;
    node = nullptr;
}
```

#### PS

Your program has undefined behavior. The value of `node1` is not `nullptr` in `main` but the object that it points to has been deleted. Dereferencing the pointer and accessing its member variable is undefined behavior.

Comment: OK thanks, I feel stupid now :P

Comment: @nathanesau, don't feel too bad. Most of us have been through such errors :)